# Angular 1.5 nesting components

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a container component that has 2 other controllers nested in it. I have them set up like so 
`container -> component1` and `container -> component2`

My train of thought here was that I could transclude the HTML from my page into my container component. 
`<container> <component1></component1> <component2></component2></container>`

and then in the container HTML `<div ng-init="vm.init()" ng-transclude></div>`

Problem is, my container isn't running at all, I added a console log to its init function and no code is running. While component1 and component2 run their init's.

Seems to be a large amount of documentation covering older angular versions. Which tell me that they need to be nested like so `<div ng-controller="parentController"> <div ng-controller="childController"></div> </div`

How do you nest components into each other in 1.5?

Comment: The [Component Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) over on angularjs.org has examples of nesting components, and there are many questions about nested components here on SO (see the Related sidebar). Right now this question is quite broad and seems to be asking for a tutorial rather than a specific answer to a specific problem...

Comment: very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was that I was attempting to put a ng-init and ng-transclude in the same element. My guess is that ng-transclude overrides everything in the element it is on.

so I moved the ng-init to another element and its working fine

`<div ng-transclude ng-init="vm.init()"></div>`

changed to

`<div ng-init="vm.init()"> <section ng-transclude ></section> </div>`